# Object in my Characer Rig is not getting animated during render

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

Can anyone help me to solve the issue where the 'Body' Object will not show the animation in the rendered view?

[image: Viewport View vs. Rendered View]

You can see the entire animation here

https://streamable.com/dwjxg7

[image: Outliner Screenshot]

[image: Dope Sheet with Armature Key Frames]

Edit: The particular object in question has shape keys for mouth movement.

Comment: Please show the modifier panel for the mesh.  Focus on the armature modifier.  What is the name of the body mesh or meshes?  Body?

Comment: Is there a backup copy of the body (in a collection or a child) that is hidden in the viewport but enabled for render?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Name of the Object is 'Body'. Its a single Mesh. This is the modifer stack. It only has one modifier which is the armature https://imgur.com/a/loaahkW I have to mention that the 'Body' object has shape keys for mouth movement.

Comment: @Blunder I have rechecked the outliner there is no backup copy of the Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvg7C.jpg

Please Enable the render button on the modifier.
This will fix your problem.

---

The little x in the button means .. do not use during render.  When enabled it will be blue like the other icons.  The render button may resemble a camera for some people. That button is meant to control use ✅render or not use for render.  Stray clicking or experimental clicking may have disabled the button

You supplied the image. I attempted to place it in this proposed answer and something failed at this site.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm ashamed I didn't spot that. Cheers.